# Download Accelerator for Unix using MobaXterm SSH

Tags: ssh, download, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm in Windows to SSH into a Unix Server.

I am trying to download a large file (>30GB) using MobaXterm and it just times out and then stops.

My question: Is there a download accelerator for MobaXterm or SSH that I can use to download this file so that it does not time out or cancel itself ?

Comment: Is it timing out or is just the desktop sleeping? Also why not doing it with a non-encrypted protocol, like HTTP or rsync, which also allows resuming failed transfers? Depending on network and connections, 30GB won't be fast, you are bound by the laws of physics, and less faster if in Wifi. You might not be using the right tool for the job, or have network limitations. However with such a broad question it is hard to tell. Dealing or debugging network problems here is also borderline out of topic, depending on context. Would be out of question talking with your local networking Helpdesk?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and show us what happened.

Comment: Does it time out at a particular size, in particular 2GB or 4GB?

Comment: Only has problems with files over 10GB.  Smaller files like 2 or 4GB work well.  I didnt provide any information about why it is timing out, because I do not know.  I am using a desktop not a laptop so its not the WiFi.  It is large a large file, so I think it is something on the server end that I am SSHing too - or just a limitation of MobaXterm.  I will try the rysnc suggestion provided below.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be possible to prevent the download from timing out.  Even if there is, there's way to little information in your question to diagnose why it's timing out.  I've transferred files > 100GB over SCP, there's nothing about SCP which implicitly prevent this.

However, while the timeouts are annoying they should't prevent you downloading the file, as long as you can resume the download after a timeout.  SCP can't naively do this AFAIK.  However [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) can.  What's more MobaXterm does include `rsync` on the command line and rsync can be tunnelled over SSH.

In MobaXterm, open up a new tab using the little "+".  You'll presented with a bash command line implemented in [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).  Your windows drives can be found under `/cygdrive`, eg:  `c:` is `/cygdrive/c`.

There's a discussion of using rsync for resume support here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20860920/453851

Short version is:

```
rsync --partial --progress --rsh=ssh user@remote_host:remote_file /cygdrive/c/Users/user/Desktop
```